# Google compute engine gcloud compute copy-files: could not fetch instance

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I am trying to copy files to my google compute engine instance from the Google Cloud SDK Shell but i can't, because of the following error message:
Could not fetch instance: -Access Not Configured. Compute Engine API has not been used in project xyz before or it is disabled. Enable it by visiting [https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/compute_component/overview?project=][1]

[1]: https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/compute_component/overview?project= then retry. If you enabled this API recently, wait a few minutes for the action to propagate to our systems and retry

I did everything i could think of. I set up the credentials for the compute engine api, i've set my GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS environment variable to the downloaded json which is something like this, but filled in:

{
  "type": "service_account",
  "project_id": "",
  "private_key_id": "",
  "private_key": "",
  "client_email": "",
  "client_id": "",
  "auth_uri": "",
  "token_uri": "",
  "auth_provider_x509_cert_url": "",
  "client_x509_cert_url": ""
}

What should i do? Thanks for everyone.

Comment: Hi I was wondering whether you ever solved this issue? As, I'm currently having the same one. (Visiting the link says that API does not exist...)

Comment: Well i did solve it but it was a pretty long time ago. I've made some notes to myself, so i'll share it with you:
STEP1, set up region: gcloud config set compute/yourzone (for example: zone us-central1-c)
STEP2, specify your project: gcloud config set project yourprojectname
STEP3, copy the files: gcloud compute copy-files /somefolder1/somefolder2/somefile.txt root@projectname:/home/somefolder --yourzone (for example: zone us-central1-c)

I hope it helps if not, please visit this page:
https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/transfer-files